# Microsoft flow mention whole team (not a single user) in a adaptive card

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to mention whole team (not a single user) in an adaptive card using Power automate

I am able to mention single user by following the steps mentioned in this link [use adaptive cards with mention in microsoft teams](https://dev.to/kenakamu/use-adaptive-cards-with-mention-in-microsoft-teams-4580)

But I am not able to mention the whole team in the card

Example
My team name is 'Test Teams', If I am posting a message manually in the teams then I can just use `@Test Teams` to mention whole team but I am not able to do the same with Microsoft Flow

Can anyone help me on this

Comment: I too tried only with single user using the adaptive cards. Also i failed to see any documentation on the same too.

Answer (score 0):

@WholeTeam remains on the backlog in Teams UserVoice,

Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams UserVoice here:

https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/